# Peek-and-Pop UIView to show SFSafariViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, 3dtouch

I have a `UITableView` and in each cell theres a `UIView` added as subview. What I currently have is a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to open the `In-App-Safari` whenever I click one of those `UIViews`. However I'm struggling to implement [Apples sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/deprecated_symbols/implementing_peek_and_pop) of the peek and pop feature for force touch. My code looks as follows:

```
 @IBOutlet var mainTableView: UITableView!
```

in *viewDidLoad()*:

```
 registerForPreviewing(with: self as! UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate, sourceView: mainTableView)
```

after *viewDidLoad()*:

```
 func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
            // First, get the index path and view for the previewed cell.
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location),
              let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
              else { return nil }

 //Enable blurring of other UI elements, and a zoom in animation while peeking.

 previewingContext.sourceRect = cell.frame

 //Create and configure an instance of the color item view controller to show for the peek.

 guard let url = someURL else { return nil }
            let vc = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
            vc.delegate = self as SFSafariViewControllerDelegate

            return vc
        }

        func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) 
{

//Push the configured view controller onto the navigation stack.

 navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerToCommit, animated: true)
}
```

`Xcode` returns errors such as

> Received memory pressure event 4 vm pressure 1

and

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewController previewingContext:viewControllerForLocation:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I haven't found a solution yet to peek and pop web content when pressing a `UIView`.

Comment: 3D touch is removed from the 2019 iPhones anyway

Comment: I still think it‘s a nice feature ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so i found out that I simply forgot to add `UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate` to my class:

```
class MyViewController: UITableViewController, UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate
```

The peek works as intended with the stated method, but for the pop to work I had to adapt my last function:

```
    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
    show(viewControllerToCommit, sender: self)
}
```